# changing value of dropdown using react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, react-hooks

I have one `edit form`. its values are getting auto populated once user click on the `edit button`. actually all the values are getting populated properly except the dropdown. its still same. how can I change the valye of `dropdown` using react hook?

[image]

below method populating data in the dropdown.

```
  const fetchStatus = async ()=>{
       const {data}= await httpClient.get( config.resourceServerUrl+"/sponsors");
           data.length>0? setResult(data): setResult([]);
    }
```

below useEffect setting the values in the field once page loaded. before that it calls above method to populate values in dropdown because it comes from database.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        fetchStatus();

        (async () => {
            const { data } = await httpClient.get(config.resourceServerUrl+"/certificates/"+id);
            setRequestStatus(data.requestStatus);
            setSponsor(data.sponsor);
            setAddress(data.address);
            setPhaseOfTrial(data.phaseOfTrial);
            setAddress2(data.address2);
            setZipCOde(data.zipCode);
            setCity(data.city);
            setprotoColNo(data.protoColNo);
     });
```

below are the react hooks I created.

```
const [requestStatus, setRequestStatus] = useState();
const [sponsor, setSponsor] = useState();
const [address, setAddress] = useState();
const [phaseOfTrial, setPhaseOfTrial] = useState();
const [address2, setAddress2] = useState();
const [zipCode, setZipCOde] = useState();
const [city, setCity] = useState();
const [protoColNo, setprotoColNo] = useState();
```

below hook is getting used for selecting the value in the dropdown..

```
const [sponsor, setSponsor] = useState();
```

what changes I need to do to select the value in dropdown once page loaded. later user can change.

I am usin `react-select` and `formik` in the page. when user will change the value in dropdown other field will also populate.

```
                         <div className="row mt-0  ">
                                     <div className="col-sm-6 pb-2 gx-5">      
                                                <label
                                                    id="sponsorLabel"
                                                    className="required form-label"
                                                >
                                                    Sponsor
                                                </label>
                                                <Select
                                                      id="sponsor" 
                                                      name="sponsor"   
                                                    // placeholder="Select the Sponsor"
                                                     className="align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                                      options={result.map((sponsor:Sponsor)=>
                                                            ({ label: sponsor.name, value: sponsor.id })
                                                      

                                                    )}
                                                    onChange={ (sponsorId:any,e:any)=>{
                                                        setFieldValue("sponsor",sponsorId.value)
                                                        result.map((sponsor:Sponsor)=>{
                                                         if(sponsorId.value===sponsor.id){
                                                         setFieldValue("address",sponsor.address);
                                                         setFieldValue("address2",sponsor.address2);
                                                         setFieldValue("zipCode",sponsor.zipCode);
                                                         setFieldValue("city",sponsor.city);
                                                         setFieldValue("sponsor",sponsor.name)
                                                         }
                                                        })
                                                     }}
                                               />

                                                <span className={styles.mandatory}>
                                                    <ErrorMessage name="sponsor" />
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                </div>
```

below is the data to populate list.

```
 const fetchStatus = async ()=>{
        const {data}= await httpClient.get( config.resourceServerUrl+"/sponsors");
            data.length>0? setResult(data): setResult([]);
 }
```

Comment: can you attach the `JSX` for the `select` ?

Comment: Are you using a library for select? Looks like it. What library, and as mentioned above you should paste the JSX part too.

Comment: thank you. i have added in question

Comment: why is here `result.map` ? `sponser` itself should have values, can you show how the data in `sponser` looks as - thanks

Comment: assuming sponser is an array of objects, it could be done as =>                               `options = {sponser.map(s => ({'value': s.name, 'label':s.id}) )}`

Comment: I put data of api in result array.

Comment: you have already set the `response` -> `sponser` to state after the API call ... so why again ?